# Dinamizar CSS com PHP vai contra as boas práticas?

Tags: php, css

Dinamizar CSS com PHP vai contra as boas práticas?

Preciso mudar a imagem de fundo do header de uma página de acordo com o artigo dela. Pensei em escrever o CSS dentro de um arquivo PHP para isso, mas não sei se é considerado uma boa prática... ou pior, uma péssima pŕatica.

OBS: Também pensei em fazer isso usando AJAX para assim que a página carregar, ele acessar o banco de dados, pegar o nome da imagem e mudar no CSS.

Comment: Eu faço uso desse artificio em alguns dos meus sites, dependendo da versão (portuguesa, italiana, espanhola ou inglesa) a imagem de fundo é a do país da versão escolhida. Não há outro jeito pois é uma unica pagina em php que constroi o html na versão escolhida. Mas vc pode fazer seu arquivo css e deixar o estilo no php  somente da parte da imagem de fundo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é uma péssima prática se você trabalha com Design Patterns e arquiteturas MVC. Porém, se você programa estruturado, não vejo problema, mas há melhores formas de criar um CSS dinâmico, com javascript e Ajax. Você pode fazer o Ajax e utilizar eventos do Jquery, por exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   context: document.body
}).success(function() {
   $( this ).css( "background-color", "#00000" );
});
```

Espero ter ajudado! Qualquer dúvida, estamos ai!

Comment: Sim, como eu disse na postagem pensei em usar o AJAX pra isso, mas imaginei que poderia ter uma forma de fazer isso no documento pelo back-end mesmo. Mas muito obrigado, pelo esclarecimento. Vou usar AJAX mesmo, uma vez que estou trabalhando com MVC. Valeu !

Comment: Sim, como você utiliza MVC, front-end e back-end não se misturam, então Javacript é a melhor forma de dinamizar o seu CSS. Abraço!